# drop a column from a multi-level column index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

## Need to drop a sub-column of multi-index data frame created from pivot table

Need to drop a sub-column only at specific columns(month) dynamically

I have a dataframe created from pivot table and need to drop a sub-column at specific columns dynamically...

**if todays date is less than 15** i need to drop the sub-column **Bill1** for all the months except **Sep-19**(**current month**)

**if todays date is greater than 15**, it should drop the sub-column **Bill1** for all the months except **Oct-19**(**next month**)

```
data_frame1 = pd.pivot_table(data_frame, index=['PC', 'Geo', 'Comp'], values=['Bill1', 'Bill2'], columns=['Month'], fill_value=0)
data_frame1 = data_frame1.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
tuples = [(a.strftime('%b-%y'), b) if a!= 'All' else (a,b) for a,b in data_frame1.columns]
data_frame1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
```

**output:**

```
              jan-19             Feb-19        Mar-19
             Bill1 Bill2      Bill1 Bill2     Bill1 Bill2     
PC Geo Comp
A  Ind   OS   1     1.28        1    1.28      1    1.28
```

**desired Output:**

```
               jan-19      Feb-19       Mar-19
               Bill2       Bill2     Bill1 Bill2     
PC Geo Comp
A  Ind   OS     1.28        1.28      1    1.28
```

Comment: Can you filter the dataframe before the `pd.pivot_table`?  This in my honest opinion would be easiest.

Comment: First I thought, filtering before pivoting would be a good idea, but I think it is not applicable in this case, because Bill1 and Bill2 are probably two columns in the source dataframe and thus can't be filtered.

Comment: @jottbe... could you please answer my question?... i have modified my question...please have a check

Comment: @jezrael... bro any help?

Comment: @PraveenSnowy: just saw your comment. Sorry, could you create a new question? It is hard to keep track of changes if a post is just edited.

Comment: Just one quick attempt. I guess you mean the text in bold above, right? Do you get the output you want, if you just change `next_month_date=datetime(next_month_year, next_month, 1)` to `next_month_date=datetime(next_month_year, next_month, 15)`?

Comment: @jottbe....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57783172/how-to-drop-values-column-of-pivot-table-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems jezrael is on vacation, so I give it a try :-)

You can do it as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

# get the date of the 1st day in the next month (using the system date)
now= datetime.now()
next_month_year, next_month= calendar.nextmonth(now.year, now.month)
next_month_date=datetime(next_month_year, next_month, 1)

# get all dates in the data for which we might have to delete columns
dates_to_correct= df.loc[df['Month'] < next_month_date, 'Month'].dt.strftime('%b-%y').unique()

# filter the columns to be deleted
cols_to_delete= [col for col in data_frame1.columns if col[1] == 'Bill1' and col[0] in dates_to_correct]
data_frame1.drop(cols_to_delete, axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

Maybe it looks a bit complicated, but because I didn't know if you just have the next month or also months farther in the furture in your data, I thought it might be safer to compare dates and not just do something like `column_string_date != string_for_next_month`.

Based on this example data

```
df= pd.DataFrame({
        'PC':    ['foo', 'bar'],
        'Geo':   ['here', 'there'],
        'Comp':  ['Telekom', 'Daimler'],
        'Bill1': [17.19, 21.23],
        'Bill2': [17.18, 21.22],
        'Month': ['2019-08-01', '2019-09-01'],
    })

df['Month']= df['Month'].astype('datetime64')
```

We get:

```
Out[56]: 
                  Aug-19 Sep-19       
                   Bill2  Bill1  Bill2
PC  Geo   Comp                        
bar there Daimler   0.00  21.23  21.22
foo here  Telekom  17.18   0.00   0.00
```